# Elasticsearch curl error Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response')

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I am using requests library to connect to elasticsearch for fetching data.  I have

```
26 indices, 
spread across 2 nodes, 
with 1st node having 16GB RAM / 8 vCPU and the 
2nd 8GB RAM / 4 vCPU.
```

All my nodes are in AWS EC2.

In all I have around 200 GB of data.  I am primarily using the database for aggregation exercises.

A typical data record would look like this

```
SITE_ID    DATE          HOUR     MAID     
123        2021-05-05     16       m434
```

I am using the following python3 definition to send the request and get the data.

```
def elasticsearch_curl(uri, json_body='',verb='get'):
        headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json',}
        try:
                resp = requests.get(uri, headers=headers, data=json_body)
                try:
                        resp_text = json.loads(resp.text)
                except:
                        print("Error")
        except Exception as error:
                print('\nelasticsearch_curl() error:', error)
        return resp_text
```

##Variables

```
tabsite :  ['r123','r234']   ##names of indices
siteid : [123,124,125]       ##name of sites
```

I am using the following code to get the data:

```
for key,value in tabsite.items():
        k=key.replace('_','')
        if es.indices.exists(index=k):
                url="http://localhost:9200/"+str(k)+"/_search"
                jb1='{"size":0,"query": {"bool" : {"filter" : [{"terms" : {"site_id": ' + str(siteid)  + '}},{"range" : {"date" : \
{"gte": "'+str(st)+'","lte": "'+str(ed)+'"}}}]}}, "aggs" : {"group_by" : {"terms": {"field": "site_id","size":100},"aggs" : {"bydate" : {"terms" : \
{"field":"date","size": 10000},"aggs" : {"uv" : {"cardinality": {"field": "maid"}}}}}}}}'

                try:
                        r2=elasticsearch_curl(url, json_body=jb1)
                        k1=r2.get('aggregations',{}).get('group_by',{}).get('buckets')
                        print(k1)
                except:
                        pass
```

The above code returns the data from r123 which has 18GB of data while it fails to get it from r234 which has 55 GB of data.

I am getting the following error:

```
elasticsearch_curl() error: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
```

I have tried the following:

1. Try running the above code in a machine which has only r234 index with around 45GB of data.  It worked.
2. I tried increasing the RAM size of the 2nd machine in production from 8GB to 16GB - it failed.

When I searched for options here, I understood I need to close the headers.  I am not sure how.

I have the following questions:

1. How do I keep my elasticsearch nodes stable without getting them shutdown automatically?
2. How do I get rid of the above error which shuts down one of the nodes or both.
3. Is there any optimimal configuration setting ratio for volume of data : number of nodes : amount of RAM / vCPUs.

Comment: did you get the cause for this? i am stuck at the same error.